# Removing '&amp' character from a string in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, replace, plsql, oracle11g, wildcard

How can I "REMOVE" &' character from a string in Oracle 11g? I tried the following by I receive a prompt that asks me 'AMP' (Enter Substitution Value) value... I don't know what's the problem. Most of the questions I found out (including one which is marked duplicate of this question) are talking about escaping the ampersand. In my situation it is a field which keeps the URL of the certain reviews and it has "&" with it which needed to be removed. Here is the code:

```
  UPDATE table_name
  set name=REPLACE(name, "&amp;", '&')
```

Please let me know if this is not the right way, then what is? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Edited my question: it is to remove '&amp;' not escape.

Answer (score 0):

Use this... Replace(name, chr (38)||'amp', '') and for like also.

Comment: 38 is ascii code of &.... chr function will convert this to & at the time of exec.. hence it will not conflict.

Comment: Thanks Vinish! It helped me a lot. It wasn't exactly the same code that you suggested by I had to tweak it a bit.